# Query to join two tables by mapping third table without returning all records from third table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I have 3 tables:

Table `Maths`:

```
ID   Marks1
(1 ,    80)
```

Table `English`:

```
ID   Marks2
(2 ,    85)
```

Table `Student`:

```
ID    Name
(1 ,    Raj)
(2 ,    Sam)
(3 ,    John)
```

I need a SQL query (Oracle) to get the following output:

```
ID Name Marks1 Marks2
(1 , Raj , 80 ,    (null))
(2 , Sam , (null) , 85)
```

Some query I wrote:

```
select B.ID, B.Name, A.Marks1, C.Marks2 from 
(select ID, Marks1 from Maths) A
full join Student B on B.ID=A.ID
left join (select ID, Marks2 from English) C
on C.ID=B.ID
```

But this query returns all records from Student table which I don't need.
I need only records from Maths and English tables.
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need rows, where student's ID is present in at least one of tables `MATHS`, `ENGLISH`. These queries gives output you wanted:

```
select id, s.name, m.Marks1, e.Marks2 
  from maths m 
    full join english e using (id)
    join student s using (id);
```

...or:

```
select s.id, s.name, m.Marks1, e.Marks2 
  from student s
    left join english e on e.id=s.id
    left join maths m on m.id = s.id
  where e.id is not null or m.id is not null
```

<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5938/1)</sup>

In first query order of joining tables is important - this is why you got incorrect output. More [informations with examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins) about joins.

Comment: How can join to another dimension table using 'using' clause. For example I have another table Grade with columns grade_id, grade_name. consider grade_id column included in English and Maths tables. Now I want to retrieve grade_name in my result set. how can I do this, please help.

Comment: I think that you need to join this additional table with left join **twice**, so add this line: `left join grade g1 on g1.grade_id = m.grade_id` and this line: `left join grade g2 on g2.grade_id = e.grade_id`. Please see attached [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a2ea1/1) for full new query.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `FULL JOIN` (full outer join - returns records when there is a row in either table) to a `JOIN` (inner join - only join when the row exists in both tables)